# I am using fowllowing code to rotate to landscape but navigation bar does not rotate. i am using Three20 navigation in my app

Tags: iphone, three20

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; {
    // First rotate the screen:
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    // Then rotate the view and re-align it: 
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(( 270.0/180*M_PI));
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(landscapeTransform, +90.0, +90.0 );
    [self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Three20 but is your class returning YES or similar in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

}

Comment: its only navigation bar doesn't rotate the whole view rotate perfectly.